# In ADO, how can Tasks have a Feature as a parent, yet not show up on the Board with Stories?

Tags: azure-devops, task, azure-boards

Why can a Task belong to a Feature, just like a Story, but not appear on the board? I want to be able to manage Stories and Tasks on the same board. Stories should have sub-tasks.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> In ADO, how can Tasks have a Feature as a parent

You could add the Feature as a parent in the related link for the task:

[image]

> Why can a Task belong to a Feature, just like a Story, but not appear
> on the board?

That is because they are displayed on Boards according to the processes or process templates that work in Azure Boards, like `Agile`:

[image]